# what does u stand for in ctrl+u?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

I was trying to understand and remember keyboard shortcuts for bash. I was wondering why is the char 'u' used in

```
CTRL-u --- cancel the line before cursor location
```

Comment: Just think of the "u" as undo

Comment: @strager on a qwerty keyboard, h is on the left, l is on the right. In ASCII, ctrl-J is linefeed and ctrl-K is vertical tab. Easy-peasy.

Answer (score 10):

While `unix-line-discard` is a good mnemonic, the use of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> as a line-erase character precedes the invention of UNIX.  It was used as such on various Digital Equipment (DEC) systems, including the PDP-8.  For instance, from my dusty bookshelf I see that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> was used as line-erase in the PDP-8 Symbolic Editor (page 5-13 of the 1972 edition of the `PDP-8 Introduction To Programming (Volume 1)` manual published by DEC).  In fact, in the early days of UNIX, the `@` character was often the default line-erase character.  Other systems used <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for the same function, which made some sense since the ASCII control character description for it is `Cancel`. The DEC convention of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> eventually won out in the popularity contest.

Comment: Ctrl-U is NAK. I suppose NAK could be twisted around to mean "do not want". ;)

Comment: @Dennis Williamson what do you mean by NAK?

Comment: @draw: It means Negative AcKnowledge. See [man ascii](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man7/ascii.7.php), the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nak) and the [Jargon File](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/N/NAK.html).

Comment: @Dennis Williamson Thanks. Right, NAK make sense too.

Answer (score 3):

"unix-line-discard": http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC17